# When is the sum of reciprocals of positive integers convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, arithmetic-progressions, ramsey-theory

I'm looking for sufficient conditions on an infinite $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_+$ so that
$$\sum_{n\in\Lambda}\frac{1}{n}<\infty.$$
I know that the contraposition of this question is given by Erdos' conjecture on arithmetic progressions, which says if $\sum_{n\in\Lambda}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$ then $\Lambda$ contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions, and there is decent computational evidence for this. Are there conjectures or (preferably) theorems for the contraposition? There are some obvious sufficient conditions, like $\Lambda$ can be indexed by a function growing like $n^p$ for some $p>1,$ but I'm looking for a weaker condition.

Comment: One sufficient condition is: There is a probability space and a sequence of mutually independent events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $P[A_n]=1/n$ for $n \in \Lambda$, and such that with probability less than 1, there are an infinite number of $n \in \Lambda$ for which $A_n$ is true.

Comment: Maybe ones that are famous and non trivial are the defective series (missing digit) have a look at [Kempner Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). There is quite a bunch of examples on the associated page [List of Sums of Reciprocals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sums_of_reciprocals) in the "infinitely many terms" section.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32988/density-and-sums-of-reciprocals